# Getting started with RTC java APIs and rest client

Tags: java, api, rest, rational-team-concert

I am new to RTC java APIs and rest client. Just started with it. Please can anyone suggest me how to get started using rest client in mozilla.
I searched a lot about it but didn't find proper latest documentations. If anyone can suggest me steps, links or any documents. It would be great.
Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.